# How to make tinymce update two elements at the same time?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'd like TinyMCE editor to update another element with the entered content exactly the way this stackoverflow's editor does when I'm asking a question :) Does anyone know the simplest way to do it?

Comment: [isDirty](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/API3:method.tinymce.Editor.isDirty) method is the way to go :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about a TinyMCE specific way to do this, but you could add an 'onchange' event to the textarea box which, when fired, can update the contents of a 'mirroring' div with the new content of the textarea.